# Android app closing on back press zxing barcode scanner

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, back-button

When back button is pressed from barcode scan `CamerActivity`, app is closed. 
This is what I'm getting in monitor.

`02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6573/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x4215a000, 8192, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6573/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x42158000, 8192, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6573/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x42156000, 8192, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6573/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x426e8000, 32768, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6573/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x426e0000, 32768, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6573/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x426d8000, 32768, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6573/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x426d0000, 32768, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-130/? W/AudioFlinger: session id 1597 not found for pid 130
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6579/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x42164000, 8192, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6579/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x42162000, 8192, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6579/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x42160000, 8192, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6579/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x4215e000, 8192, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6579/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x42708000, 32768, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6579/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x42700000, 32768, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6579/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x426f8000, 32768, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-6579/? W/MemoryDealer: madvise(0x426f0000, 32768, MADV_REMOVE) returned Operation not supported on transport endpoint
02-09 11:36:29.750 130-130/? W/AudioFlinger: session id 1598 not found for pid 130`

thanks in advance